# how to get the gaussian filter?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I want to get a Gaussian window of size `m rows` and `n columns`. 
I know how to get to 1-dimension. i.e below.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
multivariate_normal(mean=[1, 5], cov=(2.5))
```

Now I want two dimensions of a matrix. 
Purpose: I want fit this filter on top an image. the green color is a matrix of an image. Blue circle is a Gaussian filter. I am not sure how to get the blue window.

I am thinking to apply **something** like this -

```
gw = multivariate_normal(mean=[1, 5], cov=(2.5))

for i in range(image.shape[0):
    image_gauss_window[i:] = gw
```

[image]

Can you give a way to find out the Gaussian filter for an image? I see opencv many functions apply a Gaussian blur to an image. But here I want the filter before applying/convolving on top of an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a "python"ian way of creating a 2D Gaussian filter, you can create it by dot product of two 1D Gaussian filter.

Creating a single 1x5 Gaussian Filter

```
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 5, endpoint=False)
y = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=2, cov=0.5)
```

Then change it into a 2D array

```
import numpy as np
y = y.reshape(1,5)
```

Dot product the y with its self to create a symmetrical 2D Gaussian Filter

```
GF = np.dot(y.T,y)
```

Comment: this looks simple trying it out.

Comment: 2d symmetrical gauss filter === gauss filter ?

Comment: Yes. It is the same thing

Answer (score 7):

**Using [`np.fromfunction`:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html)**

You can use some code from [`a basic computer vision library`](https://github.com/RoadKillCat/PiCamVision/blob/master/vision.py) that I wrote.

So if you have `size` and `sigma`, you can get the `2d` `numpy` `array` of the `gaussian` `kernel` with this one line:

```
kernel = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: (1/(2*math.pi*sigma**2)) * math.e ** ((-1*((x-(size-1)/2)**2+(y-(size-1)/2)**2))/(2*sigma**2)), (size, size))
```

and then to `normalise` it, just divide each `element` by the `sum`:

```
kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
```

which (*for example*) with `size` as `5` and `sigma` as `1` would give `kernel` as:

```
array([[ 0.00296902,  0.01330621,  0.02193823,  0.01330621,  0.00296902],
       [ 0.01330621,  0.0596343 ,  0.09832033,  0.0596343 ,  0.01330621],
       [ 0.02193823,  0.09832033,  0.16210282,  0.09832033,  0.02193823],
       [ 0.01330621,  0.0596343 ,  0.09832033,  0.0596343 ,  0.01330621],
       [ 0.00296902,  0.01330621,  0.02193823,  0.01330621,  0.00296902]])
```

which you can see is a nice symmetric `bell-curve` in `2d` that rises in the centre.

---

You can see this `gaussian` `filter` visualised with `matplotlib`:

[image: gaussian]

Comment: Why do you do `size-1` instead of just size?

Comment: Oh upon closer inspection, I believe this has a centering effect!

Answer (score 7):

**Using openCV in Python**

Example: 5x5 kernel with Sigma=1.0:

First method: use a **matrix with a single 1 in the middle**:

```
    visualization_matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
    visualization_matrix[2,2] = 1.0
    print(visualization_matrix)
```

```
    [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

```
    gauss_kernel = cv2.GaussianBlur(visualization_matrix , (5, 5), 1.0, 
                                    borderType=cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED)
    print("Kernel: \n", gauss_kernel)
```

```
    Kernel:
    [[0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]
     [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
     [0.02193823 0.09832033 0.16210282 0.09832033 0.02193823]
     [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
     [0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]]
```

Second method: use **cv2.getGaussianKernel**:

```
    xdir_gauss = cv2.getGaussianKernel(5, 1.0)
    kernel = np.multiply(xdir_gauss.T, xdir_gauss)
    print("Kernel: \n", kernel)
```

```
    Kernel: 
    [[0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]
     [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
     [0.02193823 0.09832033 0.16210282 0.09832033 0.02193823]
     [0.01330621 0.0596343  0.09832033 0.0596343  0.01330621]
     [0.00296902 0.01330621 0.02193823 0.01330621 0.00296902]]
```

The result is the same.

Note that in Python the kernel size must be odd. So using e.g. a 4x4 kernel is not supported by the used functions.

Answer (score 3):

This function does not exist in `OpenCV`, but `OpenCV` provides the basic function to create it, which is called `cv::getGaussianKernel`. Because I am unfamiliar with python, I wrote my program in c++, but I know it is simple to convert this code to python.

```
Mat xdirectionGauss = getGaussianKernel(4,  //Size of kernel in x direction
                                        1.4);  // Sigma in x direction

Mat kernel =xdirectionGauss*xdirectionGauss.t();  //kernel * transpose(kernel)
```

`kernels` output will be like this:

```
[0.035183571, 0.058602851, 0.058602851, 0.035183571;
0.058602851, 0.097610727, 0.097610727, 0.058602851;
0.058602851, 0.097610727, 0.097610727, 0.058602851;
0.035183571, 0.058602851, 0.058602851, 0.035183571]
```

If you compare the results with MATLAB, which produced a 2D kernel, the output will be identical to opencv.

```
>> h = fspecial('gaussian',[4 4], 1.4)

h =

0.0352    0.0586    0.0586    0.0352
0.0586    0.0976    0.0976    0.0586
0.0586    0.0976    0.0976    0.0586
0.0352    0.0586    0.0586    0.0352
```